# Convert time in milisec in android

Tags: java, android, time

```
  Log.d("Time", String.valueOf(calendarSelected.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + (monthNumber+1) + "/" + year+ ", " + hour12 + ":" + min+ " " + AM_PM));
```

it returns date like

```
7/4/2014, 1:44 PM
```

I tried with this

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calendarSelected.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, (monthNumber));
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour24);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
```

But it gives me this `Tue Apr 08 01:44:01 GMT+06:00 2014` in milisec `1396899841127`.Which is wrong.

How can I covert that in MiliSec?

Comment: milliseconds since which time?

Comment: @mangusta for this 7/4/2014, 1:44 PM

Comment: Can you use System.currentTimeMillis()?

Comment: No, the question is from which time?
There are different standards, for example since the year 0, or since 01/01/1970 00:00.
It all depends. The conversion seems to be right, but it depends the starting time.

Comment: @KristjanVeskimäe yes

Comment: @KonaAhmed I mean, milliseconds are counted since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT, if you need some other starting time, you need to implement it yourself

Comment: what @mangusta is asking is for calculating millisec there should be a reference date. e.g Jan 1st 1900

Comment: You want `7/4/2014, 1:44 PM`. The question is what timezone is this because it will affect the millisecond since epoch.

Comment: Let me rephrase your question: You want to get the difference in milliseconds between 7/4/2014, 1:44 PM and the date you selected, assuming the timezone is the same?

Answer (score 1):

System.currentTimeMillis() gives you milliseconds after 1970-01-01T00:00:0 until current moment.

Define a constant with milliseconds from 1970-... until your start time. Then subtract this value from the milliseconds of currentTimeMillis.

```
private static final Long ZERO_HOUR;

static {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, (3));
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (7));
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 44);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
    ZERO_HOUR = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long diff = currentTime - ZERO_HOUR;
    System.out.println(diff);
}
```